# how to index when querying range of values mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a sql query

```
 SELECT level, data, string, soln, uid 
 FROM user_data 
 WHERE level = 10 AND (timetaken >= 151 AND timetaken <= 217) AND uid != 1
 LIMIT 8852, 1;
```

which fetches from a table with 1.5 million entries.

I have indexed using

```
alter table user_data add index a_idx (level, timetaken, uid);
```

So the issue i am facing is it takes more than 30sec to query in some cases and in somecases less than 0.01sec.

Is there any issue with the indexing here.

Edit:
Added the explain query details

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_data | range | a_idx    | a_idx | 30      | NULL | 24091 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
```

The data field in the table is a text field. Its length is greater than 255 characters in most cases. Does this cause a Issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try getting the execution plan of this query with EXPLAIN:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT level, data, string, soln, uid 
 FROM user_data 
 WHERE level = 10 AND (timetaken >= 151 AND timetaken <= 217) AND uid != 1
 LIMIT 8852, 1;
```

This is a great slide to follow through on this topic:
http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

Try adding different indexes:

- one on uid and level
- a separate one on timetaken

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the high offset. In order to select the 8853rd result, MySQL has to scan all 8852 rows before this.

Btw, using limit without order by may lead to unexpected results.

In order to speed up the queries with high offset, you should move to a since..until pagination strategy

Comment: what do u mean by pagination strategy @Darhazer